# Empty window while running UI converted python code from Figma

Tags: python, figma

To test Figma for the first time, I created a simple frame with two rectangles and renamed each to "TextBox" while using Figma. After that as per procedure i converted that to a python code and tried running it but it shows an empty window and no rectangles or text boxes. Any clues why is this happening. Here is the code i am running.

```
from tkinter import *


def btn_clicked():
    print("Button Clicked")


window = Tk()

window.geometry("907x645")
window.configure(bg = "#ee1212")
canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#ee1212",
    height = 645,
    width = 907,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge")
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)

entry0_img = PhotoImage(file = f"img_textBox0.png")
entry0_bg = canvas.create_image(
    -188.0, 85.5,
    image = entry0_img)

entry0 = Entry(
    bd = 0,
    bg = "#d9d9d9",
    highlightthickness = 0)

entry0.place(
    x = -338.0, y = 68,
    width = 300.0,
    height = 33)

entry1_img = PhotoImage(file = f"img_textBox1.png")
entry1_bg = canvas.create_image(
    -188.0, 153.5,
    image = entry1_img)

entry1 = Entry(
    bd = 0,
    bg = "#d9d9d9",
    highlightthickness = 0)

entry1.place(
    x = -338.0, y = 136,
    width = 300.0,
    height = 33)

background_img = PhotoImage(file = f"Background.png")
background = canvas.create_image(
    -266.5, 20.5,
    image=background_img)

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Float cannot be used for coordination.

```
entry0.place(
    x = 33, y = 68,
    width = 300,
    height = 33)
```

and :

```
entry1.place(
    x = 33, y = 136,
    width = 300,
    height = 33)
```

Comment: Hi can u please specify some more details I am relatively new and not at your level of understanding thanks!

Comment: You had x = -338.0 and y = 68. x is too far to the left side and out of offset. so that you can not see it. Start from x = 10 and y = 5. So you can see where the entry is placed. You should learn all by yourself.